# Virtual machine startup error, file system corruption how to, reboot

Tags: linux, centos7, xfs

My virtual machine had a power failure and forced shutdown, when I restarted it, it entered rescue mode and reported the following error, I want to know how I should start it, there is some information
in it that I need

```bash
[23.8678251XFS(sda1): Metadata corruption detected at xfs_agf_read_verify+8
×78/0×128[ xfs], xfs_agf block 8x1
[23.071343] XFS(sda1): Unmount and run xfs_repair
[23.072926] XFS(sdal): First 64 butes of corrupted metadata buffer:
```

I'm using `VMware`, image is `centos7`, vm storage is host's disk, I mean, my physical machine had a power failure, VM was forced to shut down,

[Report error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKfay.png)

Comment: You mount your disk in the host or boot with live environment and run xfs_repair as it suggests. Make backup of the VM image before doing that. To have more detailed instructions, please, elaborate your question more: what virtualization system you use, how the VM disk is stored (file in some host file system? Logical volume? ZFS pool?), what means "VM had a power failure" — a host had a power failure perhaps, VM couldn't; also, what OS distribution is used in the VM — that suggests which tools are available directly in the initramfs.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm using `VMware`, image is `centos7`, vm storage is host's disk, I mean, my physical machine had a power failure, VM was forced to shut down, as you said, I tried to use `xfs_repair`

Comment: So, what `xfs_repair -n /dev/sda1` said about you file system? Note that it should have xfs_repair utility included directly into the initramfs; you must have been able to run it from the initramfs emergency shell it dropped you into. Run xfs_repair with `-v` flag if you need more verbose output. `-n` doesn't write any changes, only detects and explains corruptions; this is safest way to run it for the first time to get an impression on the scale of the problem.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thank you very much for your patient answer, it solved my problem